# Convert such this array into variables

Tags: php, arrays

I have such this array in PHP, How can i convert the `one` and `two` and `three` into variables for each one (i have just pasted first array of the `items`)?

```
Array
(
    [encoding] => utf-8
    [title] => arrays
    [link] => arrays.com
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [one] => this is one
                    [two] => arrays.com
                    [three] => This IS my array here
                )

        )

    [items_count] => 100
    [cached] => 0
)
```

Comment: $myVar = $arr['items'][0]['one'];

Comment: `foreach($arr['items'][0] as $k => $v) $$k = $v` (note don't actually do that. But yes, you can do stuff like this in PHP)

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP's [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function:

```
extract($array['items'][0]);
```

Comment: it just works when the items contains just one array, if there are more than that, what code?

Comment: @Cab: If `items` contains multiple arrays, then how would you wish for the results to be amalgamated?  For example, what happens if more than one array defines an item with a key called `'one'`?

Answer (score 2):

a realy simple way is the  [php function `extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php). It provides you the keys of an array as variables in your current scope.

In your case just write `extract($array['items'][0]);`

Now you can access the variables `$one`, `$two` and `$three`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
list($one,$two,$tree) = $Your_Array['items'][0];
```